# Proving that $||T||=1$.

Tags: operator-theory, normed-spaces

Let  $T:l_{2} \rightarrow l_{2}$ be defined by

$$T(x) = \left(x_{1},\frac{x_{2}}{2},\frac{x_{3}}{4},\ldots,\frac{x_{n}}{2^{n-1}},\ldots \right)$$

where $x = (x_{1},x_{2},.....).$

Find $||T||$.

1-I know that I will use the formula $||T||$ = sup $\frac{||T(x)||}{||x||}$, and I know that I can not use the formula $||T||$ = $sup_{||x|| = 1} ||T(x)||$ because I am not sure that $||x||=1$, am I right?

2-I know that $$||T(x)|| = (\sum_{n = 1}^{\infty}|\frac{x_{n}}{2^{n-1}}|^2)^{1/2} = (\sum_{n = 1}^{\infty}\frac{|x_{n}|^2}{2^{2n-2}})^{1/2},$$

But after this how can I complete, especially that I previously know that the answer should be 1?

Could anyone help me please?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have $\|T(e_1)\|=1=\|e_1\|$ implies that $\|T\|\geq 1$. $\|T(x)\|^2=\sum_{n\geq 1}{{x_n^2}\over {2^{2n-2}}} \leq \sum_nx_n^2=\|x\|^2$ implies that $\|T\|\leq 1$.

Comment: What about my first question?

Comment: You can restrict to the vectors of norm 1 since ${{\|T(x)\|}\over{\|x\|}}=\|T({x\over{\|x\|}})\|$.

Comment: How is $||T(e_{1})| =1|$ ? it gives me $2/\sqrt{3}$.

Comment: @Idonotknow $T(e_1)=e_1$

Comment: yeah I saw it thank you @SahibaArora